# Get DIV that has an IMG child with an ALT "dog"?

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to get a DIV that has an IMG child with an ALT "dog" with XPath?

```
....
<div>fake<div>
<div><img alt="cat"/>sike<div>
<div><img alt="dog"/>real<div> <-- get this div
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
This XPath will do that:

```xml
//div[.//img[@alt='dog']]
```